# How to quit the pscp cmd when login to remote Linux machine failed?

Tags: batch-file, pscp

I use the below cmd inside Batch script to copy a pkg from Windows to remote Linux machine.

```
pscp -pw %machinePW% configScripts.tar %machineUN%@%machineIP%:./
```

When a given UserName or machinePW is wrong then it prints **"Access denied"** and Hangs the terminal for long time, 
How i can check the login Success or not and print some error and if Login failure case?